# Comparing Strings in javascript, strangely not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, string

I have this simple function, where I want to disable the submit button if the AJAX call to the validation servlet returns "Username is taken".  For some reason, even though the response text is "Username is taken", the console still prints out "Username is available" and the button is not disabled.  I think I am not comparing the strings properly, I am new to javascript and I would appreciate any help :)

```
function StateChanged() {
        if ((xmlHttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlHttp.status == 200)) {
            document.getElementById("userNameMessage").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
if(xmlHttp.responseText.toString()=="Username is taken")
    {
    console.log("Username is taken");
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
    }
else{
    console.log("Username is available");
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
}
}
```

Comment: Try `trim()`ing and `toLowerCase()`ing the string.

Comment: ... and check the length of the response text.

Comment: ... and use the `===` operator, not `==`. (Not related to the problem, just something I noticed.)